# Cannot get === string.length to work correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have code that checks if a user has entered text into an input field. If the field is empty I want to display: you have not started.

If the field has a length greater than 1 - I want to display: you've finished. My code below works for determining when the user is finished but displays nothing saying you have not started. Any thoughts? Thanks!

HTML:

```
<p id="progressDisplay"> </p>



<p id="response"> </p>
<p id="response2"> </p>
```

JS:

```
var progress =($("#progressDisplay").text());


if( progress.length === 0 ){
    $("#response2").text("You have not entered anything yet")
}

if( progress.length > 1){
    $("#response").text("You've Finished this section")
}
```

Comment: And where is the code that detects when a change is made? The code does not keep running.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whitespace in the element is included in its text value. Your element starts with a single whitespace character, so it always has a `length > 0`.

Trim the text to avoid whitespace, for that you can use native JavaScript **[`String#trim`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim)** method.

```
var progress = $("#progressDisplay").text().trim();
```

or use **[`jQuery.trim()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/)** method.

```
var progress = $.trim($("#progressDisplay").text());
```

Comment: @epascarello : _when the user is finished __but displays nothing__ saying __you have not started__._

Comment: @AndrewLeonardi : glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

It's because in the `<p>` you have white space:

> `<p id="progressDisplay"> </p>`

This white space will count as text and will be picked up when getting the `.text()` of the paragraph.

A better way will be to either remove the white space manually or use the `.trim()` method which does not include white space.

Also, a bit on comparisons:

`===`

Compares the `type` of the variable as well as just it's value. For example:

`2 === 2` will be **true**
`2 === "2"` will be **false** *(as one is a integer and one is a string)*

If you do not want to compare the type but only the value, use: `==`

Answer (score -1):

Why not use else? See fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/6cge9rLb/

```
if( progress.length > 1){
    $("#response").text("You've Finished this section")
}else{
    $("#response2").text("You have not entered anything yet")
}
```

Comment: That's true, but it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @DavidSherret explain how this does not solve the OP's issue https://jsfiddle.net/6cge9rLb/

Comment: Code is 100% the same as the original code. With two ifs, it will not go into the other, all this does is change performance

Comment: @epascarello sure it is.

Comment: @epascarello would it make you feel all warm and fuzzy if I added an onchange event?

Comment: How is it different.... if() if() is not differnet than if() else() when the if conditions are not going to allow code to go into both ifs.

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith :  read the question carefully ... _If the field has a __length greater than 1__ - I want to display: __you've finished. My code below works for determining when the user is finished but displays nothing saying you have not started.___

Comment: @PranavCBalan thank you for the clarification, first person with a valid comment.

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith : actually whitespace is problem here

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith I have to admit I did find this advise helpful in addition to the whitespace response so thanks for the assist!

Comment: @PranavCBalan I get what you are saying, it is just that my code does solve the problem, a different approach but it still works. if this **My code below works for determining when the user is finished but displays nothing saying you have not started** is true that would make this approach ok.

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith : if he don't want to do nothing if there is single character which is not whitspace, then it will fails .... otherways it will fine :)

Comment: @AndrewLeonardi it is why despite downvotes, I stuck to my answer. May not have been the best "answer" but it was worth mentioning.

Comment: @PranavCBalan honestly, the only reason I continued down this line was because of all the negative voting, I get it, its not a great answer `-1` ok we now have like what, at some point it was -6, umm I am sure it is not that bad lol!